# Windows, how to grant access to disk raw data to standard user?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, permissions

I have to let users read all disk data ("all" means from first to last sector) from a USB pendrive, is it possibile without admin privileges in Windows>=7?

I tried some test with a custom code, and I can access this path: **\\.\PhysicalDrive2** only as admin.